# regular expression to catch whole div block over multiple lines

Tags: regex, nginx

How I can catch this whole block in a HTML Output? Inside the block is a not opened "noscript" tag.

I use it with subs_filter on nginx, means any DOM based solutions will not work here.

```
...
<div id="me_104" >
<img src="http://www.google.com" alt="" style="position: absolute; left:0; top: 0; width: 0px; height: 0px;" />
        <iframe id="zz_3423_543534" name="zz_3423_543534_54635677" src="http://google.com"  width="400" height="80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe></noscript>
</div>  
...
```

Comment: What are the parts of this block that may change ?

Comment: @Alex img src can change, the iframe id, name, src can change. the html structure stays at is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
<div\s+id\s*=\s*"me_\d+"\s*>\s*<img[^>]+>\s*<iframe[^>]+></iframe></noscript>\s*</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it don't catch it.

Comment: Update: the Regex work but not with the subs_filter on nginx, because it parses line by line.

Answer (score 1):

If you never have another div within the div, you can try something like this:

```
<div id="me_104" >.*?</noscript>.*?</div>
```

or

```
<div.*?>.*?</noscript>.*?</div>
```

or something like Alex did define the opening div

If you want to only match if there is no opening noscript tag you could use a negativ lookahead like this:

```
<div.*?>(?:(?!<noscript>|</div>).)*</noscript>.*?</div>
```

See on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9t83elXhas)

You will have to use a "dot matches newlines" flag.

Or do this:

```
<div.*?>(?:(?!<noscript>|<\/div>)(?:.|\n))*<\/noscript>(?:.|\n)*?<\/div>
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/sGe6vytEHa)

Comment: Thank you but both don't catch them.

Comment: The problem probably was the dot not matching new lines. Please have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Update: the Regex work but not with the subs_filter on nginx, because it parses line by line.